# Android Emulator VCPU Shutdown request

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm tryng to use the Android Studio Emulator in an old laptop - I have done many tries and seems that the CPU is able to make the emulator running.
The CPU is a Core i7 Q720, in win 8.1 the system react at the same manner so now I'm in a fresh Win 10 Pro installation.
When I try using the IDE of Android Studio to launch emulator I receive a non detailed error, so in terminal I can get:

```
.\emulator-check.exe hyper-v
hyper-v:
1
Hyper-V is disabled
hyper-venter code here
```

and

```
.\emulator-check.exe cpu-info
cpu-info:
146
Intel CPU|Virtualization is supported|64-bit CPU|
cpu-info
```

and

```
.\emulator-check.exe accel
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
accel:
0
HAXM version 7.6.5 (4) is installed and usable.
accel
```

So it seems fine, but when I launch a machine, in superuser or not I see for an instant the emulator and then closes, and my guesses are that is the VCPU request that closes it but I do not know why... Any suggestion from where to start searching?

```
.\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 -feature -Vulkan
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\[MyUser]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\[MyUser]\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 1.1.1.1
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
WARNING | Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 @unknown]
INFO    | added library C:\Users\[MyUser]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\vulkan\vulkan-1.dll
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\[MyUser]\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_7448.ini
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 1080x2220, dpi: 440x440
VCPU shutdown request
WARNING | Not saving state: RAM not mapped as shared
```

Thanks

In my tries, switched from Win 8.1 to fresh Win10 pro, unistalling HAMX, reinstalling it, BlueStacks works, VirtualBox not

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done some other homeworks and got it!
After some changes the Oracle VM is started, and it gives me a feeling that also the emulator should work.

Now, reading logs from Android Studio my attention come to this extract:

```
2023-08-03 14:46:13,039 [  95612]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - Activated packet streamer for bluetooth emulation
2023-08-03 14:46:13,777 [  96350]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
2023-08-03 14:46:13,777 [  96350]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - - Start Android Studio
2023-08-03 14:46:13,777 [  96350]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
2023-08-03 14:46:13,778 [  96351]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - - Click "SDK Tools" tab
2023-08-03 14:46:13,778 [  96351]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
2023-08-03 14:46:13,778 [  96351]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - - Click "OK"
```

Obviously the installed version of Emulator is that bundled with Giraffe, so with the SDK Manager I can't do nothing than reinstalling the same (wich not resolve my problem), so checking around and found nothing I finally came to

https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

and after installing last version it started to work. Slowly cause restrictions of my platform but works.

So the version shipped with Android Studio won't work and is necessary to update to last emulator in the old fashion of manual installation.
As a special note, the logs report now like before that the emulator is still to be updated, so the problem was not an old version but the version per se.